# Unity rotate object around local axis

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to rotate an object around it's local axis (In this case a humanoid index finger) with my custom editor.

```
public float amount;

void OnGUI() {
    amount = EditorGUILayout.Slider("Rotate Amount", amount, 0, 100);
    index1.transform.localEulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, amount);
}
```

The issue I am having is when I move the slider, the finger rotates down and forward so the tips of the fingers point outwards, when in theory they should point towards the elbow.

I think I am using the wrong type of transform here, so what should I do to use the right transform?

[image: Rotation 1]
[image: Rotation 2]
[image: Rotation 3]

Comment: I think screenshots would be great here, including the axes of the object. It's hard to visualize which directions you mean. (You have tried x, y, and z, right?)

Comment: I have added the images, and I have tried all axises

Answer (score 1):

Try to use:

```
index1.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, amount), Space.World);
```

or

```
index1.transform.Rotate(new Vector3(0, 0, amount), Space.Self);
```

Hope it solves your problem :)

Comment: Tried the negated value, 0 to -100?

Comment: That will just rotate it the other way

Answer (score 0):

There may be 2 parts to this:

1. Getting the current rotation of the object on the local z-axis, here's one way to do that. https://stackoverflow.com/a/47841408/228738
2. Using the current rotation value to find the amount of rotation to apply to the object.

code for step #2

```
var currentZEuler = zRotation(this.transform.rotation).eulerAngles.z;
var deltaZEuler = amount - deltaZEuler;
index1.transform.Rotate(0, 0, deltaZEuler, Space.Self);
```